# What would be the proper sql query to use, in order to echo from my two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've spent months trying to figure out table joins with no luck of finding a tutorial I can understand.

Basically, I have two tables. My 'Clients' table stores the ID of a property, which can be found in another table called 'Properties'.

I would like to echo (from the Properties table) the property address (civic, street, etc) instead of using the ID of the property from the clients table.

Current

[image: current]

An example of what I would like

[image: An example of what I would like]

To begin, my current sql query looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once "../include/connect-c.php";

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

My echo's look like this:

```
<? echo $rows['primaryProperty']; ?>
```

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *.clients, CONCAT(properties.civic, ' ', properties.street) AS propert_address FROM clients LEFT JOIN properties ON clients.primaryProperty = properties.property
```

If you run this query and echo out `$row['property_address']` it would output `123 Fakestreet`

This will select all fields from properties and clients matching the primary property from clients to property from properties.

Note: mysql_* functions are deprecated and I suggest you switch to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: looks like this is a duplicate of your first question ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying to edit but somewhy it got inserted as a new answer. I deleted the previous one.

Comment: I got an '500 internal server error', I'm not sure how to go about echoing the previous columns, e.g.: <? echo $rows['name']; ?> OR <? echo $rows['name.clients']; ?> ... SORRY MAN, this is crazy difficult for me. EDIT: disregard the 500 error.

Comment: echo $rows['name']; is what you want